# Duplicated IDs pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes (df1,df2):

| ID | Q1 |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 112 | 1 |

| ID | Q2 |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 5 |
| 112 | 7 |

Since the IDs are duplicated, I want to reinitialize them, using the following code:

```
df1.sort_values('ID',inplace=True)
df1['ID_new'] = range(len(df1))
df2.sort_values('ID',inplace=True)
df2['ID_new'] = range(len(df2))
```

in order to have smth like this:

| ID_new | ID | Q1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 111 | 2 |
| 1 | 111 | 3 |
| 2 | 112 | 1 |

| ID_new | ID | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 111 | 1 |
| 1 | 111 | 5 |
| 2 | 112 | 7 |

The question is: are we sure that the `ID_new` will be the same for `df1` and `df2`?
For example:
is it possible that `ID_new = 1` corresponds to the first `ID=111` in `df1` and to the second `ID = 111` in `df2`?

If yes, there is another way to reinitialize it in a more robust way?

Comment: Are dataframes exactly the same length? In theory, it's not possible because you can't determine the right pairs for Q1 and Q2. Why `2 <-> 1`,  `3 <-> 5` and not `2 <-> 5` and `3 <-> 1`?

Comment: yes you can't determine it...